# How to customize cucumber report template?

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am using cucumber with watir and want to customize html output report template and content. 
For example, I want to change the default heading, display pass/fail summary using different fonts etc.

Any suggestion/solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already gone through the [Cucumber wiki page for custom formatters](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters)?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find my answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried or which specific part you are stuck on?

Comment: I like to output default cucumber html format to some other format. For example, I just want to display pass rate in html output

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "display pass rate in html output" yet you say you want some other format. If you could mock up a picture of what you want, it would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/#custom-formatters

I guess this is what you are looking for.